# Security Classic ASP

Tags: ajax, angularjs, vbscript, asp-classic

Is this secure enough? I don't have any experience with classic ASP or VBScript.

I have a classic ASP page that takes in form data and sends it to another classic ASP page that makes a connection to the database. I use this for my CSRF token on the form input page:

```
<%
Dim token
token = CreateGUID()

Function CreateGUID()
  Dim tmpTemp
  tmpTemp = Right(String(4,48) & Year(Now()),4)
  tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4,48) & Month(Now()),2)
  tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4,48) & Day(Now()),2)
  tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4,48) & Hour(Now()),2)
  tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4,48) & Minute(Now()),2)
  tmpTemp = tmpTemp & Right(String(4,48) & Second(Now()),2)
  CreateGUID = tmpTemp
End Function
%>
<input type="hidden" ng-model="user.token" value="<%=token%>">
```

I'm using an AJAX call (with AngularJS if that matters) in the same page to post the form data to the page that will make a connection to the database.That page looks like this:

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBScript" %>
<%If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then%>

    <%If Request.Form("token") = Session("token") Then %>
        'here I make connection to database and and insert rest of form data in database
```

Comment: What's with the [tag:asp.net] tag? Your talking about Classic ASP and VBScript these are different to ASP.Net so which is it?

Comment: Also calling that function a `CreateGUID()` is really misleading as that is not a **true** [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier).

Comment: Approach is ok, but I would be inclined to store `token` in a separate cookie with a unique name you specify rather then relying on a session cookie to store the value.

Comment: OK. ASP.NET tag removed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so let's go over this bit by bit...

You're getting all the fields of the current date and time, and using `Right(..., 2)` along with `String(4,48)` to zero-pad them. And then you concatenate them together. This results in... A string that represents the current date and time. For example, running this right now for me produces `20141212131100`.

Firstly, it's definitely not a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier), which is carefully specified to be dependent on time, hardware info and a bit of random. Clearly, as soon as someone sees this token, they will understand how it's made and how to forge it. They only need to be accurate to the nearest minute too! There is absolutely no randomness in this token generator.

So to answer your question, no, it's not secure. If you don't have access to a COM object that can generate real GUIDs or UUIDs, how about just using a long random number instead? It wouldn't be perfect, but it would be far better than what you have right now.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd help out a little more by showing you how to generate a true GUID from VBScript.

```
Function NewGUID()
    Dim TypeLib : Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
    NewGUID = CStr(TypeLib.Guid)
End Function
```

If you use this as your anti-CSRF token then it should be as safe as any other solution out there.